# Is there a way to change the field name in the returned JSON?

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

I am returning a JSON payload from the ServiceNow API via a query using Postman. Currently, the name of the fields in the result are the field names from the ServiceNow table. Is there a way to "rename" the field to something different.

For instance:
Original:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "phone": "123-456-7890",
            "user_name": "micmou",
            "name": "Mickey Mouse"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "phone_number": "123-456-7890",
            "id": "micmou",
            "full_name": "Mickey Mouse"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I would find it bizarre for a REST API to allow overriding fields names via the request itself. Why don't you do this on the client side ?

Comment: I can via the system that will actually call the URL. Since the fields that I want returned are in sysparm_fields, I thought that maybe I could prefix the actual field name with the value I wanted. Something like full_name#name.

Answer (score 0):

The API is always going to return what is defined in the "dictionary entry" as column name for that field. Easy way to check is to do a right-click on the record and click Export -> XML (this record). The XML tags will show the field names.

I see you having 2 options: (1) change the value in the column name for that lists table definition. I do NOT recommend this since so much of the rest of the platform is going to look for the OOB column names. It will break a lot of things. or (2) create a new field in the table called whatever you like and have the field of interest copied to that new field (and updated) whenever its created or edited through a business rule. Then you can specify that new field be returned in your API call.